# Lie algebra "semi" coinvariants

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, lie-algebras, lie-algebra-cohomology

In the process of my research, I've come across the need to understand the following construction:

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a (finite-dimensional) complex Lie algebra, $\beta\in \mathfrak{g}^*$ a Lie character. Define a functor $\mathfrak{E}_\beta\colon \operatorname{Mod}(\mathfrak{g})\to\mathrm{Vect}$ from the category of $\mathfrak{g}$-modules to the category of ($\mathbb{C}$-)vector spaces by
$$\mathfrak{E}_\beta(M)=\frac{M}{\{\theta-\beta(\theta) : \theta\in \mathfrak{g}\}\cdot M}.$$
So, when $\beta=0$, this is just the space $M/\mathfrak{g}M$ of coinvariants of $M$, and the derived functors of $\mathfrak{E}_0$ are just Lie algebra homology.

What I'm interested in is vanishing criteria for $\mathfrak{E}_\beta$ and its (left) derived functors. Is there a name that the derived functors $L_i\mathfrak{E}_\beta$ go by in the literature? Are there any "canonical" references for these?

Comment: By "Lie character" I simply mean an element of the dual Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}^*$. If I recall correctly, Verma modules use central characters.

Comment: Okay, in that case I misspoke, this functor is tensoring by $U(\mathfrak{g})/(X - \beta(X))$ which is no longer guaranteed to be $1$-dimensional, but the derived functors are still given by Tors $\text{Tor}_i(U(\mathfrak{g})/(X - \beta(X)), -)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I agree that the derived functors are given by Tors. However, it would be nice to know whether such Tors have been studied in the literature.

Comment: What "dual Lie algebra"? $\mathfrak{g}^*$ is not a Lie algebra, it's just the dual as vector space and if it carries some structure reflecting being dual of a Lie algebra it would rather be a [Lie coalgebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_coalgebra).

Comment: @YCor Now that you mention it, I’m not quite sure whether I want $\beta$ to just be some element of $\mathfrak{g}^*$ or an actual Lie algebra homomorphism to $\Bbb C$.

Comment: When $\beta$ is an actual homomorphism, this construction is equivalent to taking ordinary Lie algebra homology of a twist of $M$. I am unaware of any way to define your functor when $\beta$ is an arbitrary element of $\mathfrak{g}^*$. BTW, perhaps the most prominent example of this is in the case where your Lie algebra is a maximal nilpotent $\mathfrak{n}$ inside a semisimple Lie algebra, e.g. (finite) Drinfeld-Sokolov reduction. But there the interest comes from the fact that you assume that your $\mathfrak{n}$-modules have more structure (usually you consider $\mathfrak{g}$-modules).